# A better way to create JavaScript files with namespace and subnamespace

Tags: javascript

I was looking for the best solution the best solution for using namespaces and subnamespaces in any number of JavaScript files. I read a lot of articles and answers on StackOverflow and my choice is [JavaScript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

But I have one problem how to avoid adding namespace definition to each file with only subnamespace defintion:

```
// How to avoid namespace definition
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));

// I want to have only this
appModule.sub2 = (function (ns) {
  ns.publicFunction5 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction5 from sub2AppModule.js');
  };

  return ns;
}(appModule.sub2 || {}));
```

Maybe is better way to use namespace and subnamespace in multiple files in **Pure JavaScript**.

My whole example to better understand my case.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test namespace and sub-namespace in multiple files</title>
    <!-- order is intentional to check any order attaching files -->
    <script src="sub2AppModule.js"></script>
    <script src="sub1AppModule2.js"></script>
    <script src="sub1AppModule.js"></script>
    <script src="appModule2.js"></script>
    <script src="appModule.js"></script>
    <script>
      function testNamespace() {
        console.log(appModule.publicVariable1);
        appModule.publicFunction1();
        appModule.publicFunction2();
        appModule.sub1.publicFunction3();
        appModule.sub1.publicFunction4();
        appModule.sub2.publicFunction5();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test namespace</h1>
    <button onclick="testNamespace()">Run test</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

**appModule.js**

```
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  var privateVariable1 = 'privateVariable1';

  function privateFunction1() {
    console.log('privateFunction1 from appModule.js');
  }

  ns.publicVariable1 = 'publicVariable1 from appModule.js'; 

  ns.publicFunction1 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction1 from appModule.js');
    console.log('publicFunction1 display  ' + privateVariable1);
    console.log('publicFunction1 call ' + privateFunction1());
    // Call function from nested namespace
    appModule.sub2.publicFunction5();
  };

  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));
```

**appModule2.js**

```
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  ns.publicFunction2 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction2 from appModule2.js');
  };

  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));
```

**sub1AppModule.js**

```
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));

appModule.sub1 = (function(ns) {
  ns.publicFunction3 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction3 from sub1AppModule.js');
    // Call function from parent namespace
    appModule.publicFunction2();
  };

  return ns;
}(appModule.sub1 || {}));
```

**sub1AppModule2.js**

```
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));

appModule.sub1 = (function (ns) {
  ns.publicFunction4 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction4 from sub1AppModule2.js');
  };

    return ns;
}(appModule.sub1 || {}));
```

**sub2AppModule.js**

```
var appModule = (function(ns) {
  return ns;
}(appModule || {}));

appModule.sub2 = (function (ns) {
  ns.publicFunction5 = function() {
    console.log('publicFunction5 from sub2AppModule.js');
  };

    return ns;
}(appModule.sub2 || {}));
```

**[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UMcq3k5DtGAFhs9WlRPl?p=preview)**

Comment: Why do you want to make your life harder just for fun?... Namespaces are a must in languages that don't have code organization structures such as closures, anonymous and self executing functions, but you are programming in Javascript, you have all that already. There's actually very little need for namespaces and absolutely no need for sub namespaces in Javascript, so why to waste time, energy and CPU cycles trying to implement a paradigm that provides no real benefit?... Why don't you just develop a function to load your code in the proper order and get rid of problems?

Comment: It's not that simple. I have a lot of applications that use a common tool JavaScript code (our and extern - a large number of JavaScript files). In these applications, there is a conflict of names of variables and functions in the application file and the names of variables and functions in the common files. So I have to give tips to resolve these conflicts in these applications.

Comment: I do understand your problem, however I am unable to figure out a valid reason for the additional level of complexity. You are not loading the files dynamically, so all the files will be loaded before testNameSpace executes and due to this fact, to bind sub1 to appModule is an option but not a imperative need, so instead you can keep it one level deep by using: appModuleSub1. Form my point of view, unless you already have plans to load the files dynamically I see no reason to complicate your life for free.

Comment: In the future, I do not exclude to load the files dynamically. But now, for me it is too big undertaking. So I want to use JavaScript Module Pattern to solve my problem. If I understand you are recommending the use of appModule, appModuleSub1 and appModuleSub2 than appModule, appModuleSub1, appModuleSub2. But why, for simplicity?

Comment: Why on http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html is written: _Sub-modules Our final advanced pattern is actually the simplest. There are many good cases for creating sub-modules. While this may have been obvious, I thought it worth including. Sub-modules have all the advanced capabilities of normal modules, including augmentation and private state._ So why Ben Cherry is recommended it?

Comment: One more thing. Do I close my way to use dynamic loading (e.g. required.js) by now using JavaScript Module Pattern?

Comment: Since you are loading the files form the HTML code, I don't see any functional difference between appModule.sub1 and appModuleSub1, so if I were you I'd make my life simpler. I never said the Module Pattern was the wrong answer, your approach is correct, however looking at your code I don't think there is a need for a second level of complexity, but if you feel you do need that, the only way to avoid creating the parent namespace inside the sub modules is to make sure that all the files are loaded and executed in the right order, otherwise you won't be able to get rid of it in a safe way.

Comment: You must understand that code is there to prevent the case where a sub module is loaded before the module, so you may optimize but you can't avoid that step unless you can be absolutely positive no sub module will be loaded or executed before the module.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments. I consider your tips.

Comment: Now... If you have a piece of code that must act as module in some cases and as sub module in others, then you should seriously consider the possibility of dynamically loading the files.

Comment: Should I use the required.js or something else?

Comment: What if every application will use only one namespace (app1 - app1Module.js, app2 - app2Module.js) that it will not conflict with common util JavaScript files. Does it make sense to use e.g. required.js (not too heavy caliber)?

Comment: I can't recommend you any library solution since I have my own code for that, it is actually too easy: ne = document.createElement("script"); ne.type = "text/javascript"; ne.src = "filename.js"; sorry don't know how to format code here.

Comment: Obviously the goal of the namespace will be defeated if you start duplicating namespace's names, so you must be careful to assign each module with a unique name or otherwise you will be forced to develop a namespace management module.